# How to trigger multiple Jenkins jobs remotely using an HTTP request

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to trigger multiple Jenkins jobs remotely using only jenkins url http://xxxxxx/?

Job name and parameters should be passed as script or json format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the jobs to enable the option named `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` under `Build triggers` where you need to enable the option and choose some authentication token.

[image]

You will also need to get the `API token` for your user to trigger the job. Log in to your Jenkins and in top-right corner click on your username and hit `Configure` button and create a new API token.

You can then invoke your job for example with curl:

`curl -u <user>:<api_token> "http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/build?token=<job_token>"`

To build the job with parameters, substitute `/build` with `/buildWithParameters` and pass the parameters in form of =, e.g.:

`curl -u <user>:<api_token> "http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/buildWithParameters?token=<job_token>&<param1_name>=<param1_value>&<param2_name>=<param2_value>"`...